# How can I get 'which updated fields can trigger to Dynamics CRM workflow'?

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

I have a custom workflow activity.
The workflow has been triggered by one of 10 specific fields updated.

I need these 10 fields what are they in my custom workflow. Is there any way I can get this information in custom workflow?

[image]

**Edited After Aron's comment:**

I try Aron's solution. It works, but some fields are missing.

For example, I have 7 fields (include the address field) to trigger my workflow as below.

[image]

[image]

But TriggerOnUpdateAttributeList has only 4 fields as below.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Workflow entity has a field called `TriggerOnUpdateAttributeList` which contains what you're looking for.

One way to access it would be a FetchXML query:

```
<fetch top="1" >
    <entity name="workflow" >
        <attribute name="name" />
        <attribute name="primaryentity" />
        <attribute name="triggeronupdateattributelist" />
        <filter>
            <condition attribute="name" operator="eq" value="My Workflow" />
            <condition attribute="triggeronupdateattributelist" operator="not-null" />
        </filter>
    </entity>
</fetch>
```

In the result, the `TriggerOnUpdateAttributeList` contains a comma separated list of the logical names of the fields:

```
<result>
    <name>My Workflow</name>
    <primaryentity name="" formattedvalue="2">2</primaryentity>
    <triggeronupdateattributelist>firstname,lastname,parentcustomerid</triggeronupdateattributelist>
</result>
```

Comment: Hey Aron, thank you. It worked but I have 7 fields, triggeronupdateattributelist has 4 fields. I don't understand why?

Comment: Hmm... that's interesting. Maybe post a screenshot of the fields you have selected and the list that's in `triggeronupdateattributelist`.

Comment: Hey Aron, could you check my answer? I try to share selected fields and triggeronupdateattributelist.

Comment: Thanks, that helps. The `Address1_Composite` field is a special system-calculated field. It appears not to be valid as a workflow trigger, which to me makes sense. Does the workflow actually trigger if you change one of the address1 fields (like `Address1_City`)? If not you can check on the individual Address 1 fields as triggers. What other fields are checked on as triggers but missing from the list? p.s. if `Address1_Composite` is not a valid trigger, it would be nice if Microsoft automatically excluded it from the list.

Comment: Thank you, Aron. It makes sense. For example, when I changed the Address1_City, Address1_Composite changes and It triggers the workflow. It works well. But there is a bigger problem than Address1_Conposite. EmailAddress1 and MobilePhone fields are included in my trigger list but I don't see them in the TriggerOnUpdateAttributeList. (I add a screenshot about this to the question)

Comment: Thanks for the update. It's good to know that `Address1_Composite` is valid as a trigger. I've always used the individual address fields. `EmailAddress1` should definitely be a valid trigger. If you change a Contact's email address does the workflow launch?

Comment: Hi Aron. Yes, EmailAddress1 is triggering the workflow. I figured out what is going on. I created a workflow and select the firstname,lastname,parentcustomerid as triggered fields. After a couple hours, I deactivated workflow and add EmailAddress1, then activated workflow again. TriggerOnUpdateAttributeList only has first 3 fields. The new adding field doesn't include in this attribute. I've tested it several times, and it worked like this.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the update. I looked in the `Xaml` field and didn't see the triggers defined there. I also checked the `ProcessTrigger` entity which seems to hold the triggers for Business Rules. According to [this article](https://www.crmonce.com/2017/09/how-to-update-dynamics-365-workflow.html) the `TriggerOnUpdateAttributeList` is where the triggers are defined... If you're on Dynamics 365 Online maybe open a Microsoft Support Ticket to see if they can explain the behavior you're seeing.